# Error using Active Directory in SonarQube

Tags: active-directory, ldap, sonarqube

I've been trying to configure Sonar with Active Directory for a while with no luck so I was really excited to see the new LDAP 1.5 plug-in. Unfortunately it's still not working for me but it's so close! The lookup is successful but then something fails:

```
DEBUG web[w.s.NegotiateSecurityFilter] logged in user: CORP\My.UserName (S-1-5-21-1305660829-1405082133-723345943-15257)
DEBUG web[w.s.NegotiateSecurityFilter] roles: CORP\My.UserName, CORP\Domain Users, Everyone, BUILTIN\Administrators, BUILTIN\Users, NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK, NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users, NT AUTHORITY\This Organization, [etc.]
INFO  web[w.s.NegotiateSecurityFilter] successfully logged in user: CORP\My.UserName
DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.w.s.s.SsoAuthenticationFilter] Validating authenticated user
DEBUG web[http] GET /sessions/new?return_to=%2F | time=1527ms
ERROR web[rails] Error from external users provider: exception Java::Com4j::ComException: 80040e37 (Unknown error) : A referral was returned from the server.
DEBUG web[http] GET /ldap/validate | time=1738ms
```

This was with the Negotiate protocol but I got the same error using the default NTLM protocol as well. Running Sonar 5.2.

Comment: I have opened a Google Group discussion around this topic, as I could see the group over there is more active when it comes to troubleshooting: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/XntaLr-w8yY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1.5.1 update fixed this issue for me.

https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/LDAP-49